# Fatal error initializing plugin com.android.tools.ndk solutions

Tags: android, android-studio-3.5.1

I tried to create a new project in my android studio on my linux and it keeps giving me this error "Fatal error initializing plugin com.android.tools.ndk" please I need help

I restarted my pc

Fatal error initializing plugin com.android.tools.ndk

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh this can be niggly sometimes!
Trying checking for updates, sometimes that can fix the problem.

It will be under file... Check for updates.. or something similar - i'm unfamiliar with the Linux layout.